# how to exit the program immediately using method

Tags: ruby

Is there some built-in method that can exit my program immediately?

Should I just use an Exception to quit?

Comment: Why not to give a try `exit(0)`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you could use this

```
Kernel.exit!
```

**Note:** This would exit your execution and stop the server

Comment: *"This would [...] stop the server"* - what server?

Comment: Any web server if its running.

Comment: `Kernel` namespace is redundant. Exit status code as provided in C version in OP is missing. Banged version differs from C’s `exit 0`. The “any web server running” won’t be stopped. Why for God’s sake this answer is accepted?